# Meteor.js template reactivity keep some data

Tags: templates, meteor

Using meteor.js and i am kind of stuck with the structure of template or how to do this trick as clear as possible.

Example of my chating app problem:

chatingWith = DB query for selecting each user i am chating with like on FB // REACTIVE

```
{{#each chatingWith}}
  {{#each this.messages}}
     Message1...
     Message2...
  {{/each}}
  <form>
     <input class="sendMessage" type="text" />
  </form>
{{/each}}
```

This works exactly as i need but with one big problem... when new message arrive... the content is re-rendered ofc and when i am in this time writing a message the value of  will dissapear.

How would you solve this?

Sorry for english and thx for tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a section in the documents about preserving inputs. http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve

From my understanding, as long as you have the package preserve-inputs installed, it should keep the reactive nature of meteor from erasing the input. I would check to see if the preserve-inputs package is installed.

Comment: Hm... meteor add preserve-inputs
preserve-inputs: already using

Comment: By default, new Meteor apps automatically include the preserve-inputs package. This preserves all elements of type input, textarea, button, select, and option that have unique id attributes or that have name attributes that are unique within an enclosing element with an id attribute. To turn off this default behavior, simply remove the preserve-inputs package  This is from the documents. Try added a name to the input.

Comment: I have read it but i overread this: or that have name attributes that are unique within an enclosing element with an id attribute. This was the problem! excelent man thanks for help! :)